# Hot to count commas and separate it in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonconvert

I have a URL that responds with plain text:

```
2021-12-29,,,135,1, 2021-12-30,,,135,1, 2021-12-31,9999,,135,8,
```

They are three registers:

```
2021-12-29,,,135,1, 
2021-12-30,,,135,1, 
2021-12-31,9999,,135,8,
```

I need to convert it to JSON so then I can use it a for [line graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js). So first I need to count 5 commas and separate it.

I work with a very simple HTML, JavaScript and jQuery file.

Comment: @JacobA It should be split each 6 commas.

Answer (score 2):

If the string is in that format (without exceptions), then you could easily extract an array from it with:

```js
const url = "2021-12-29,,,135,1, 2021-12-30,,,135,1, 2021-12-31,9999,,135,8,";
const rg = /\S*,/g;
const result = url.match(rg);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Samuli Hakoniemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212878/samuli-hakoniemi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69018627/14956277) is good if you have spaces after the fifth commas.

If you don't, you can use a slightly longer pattern to match. ([Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ZKnvN/1))

```js
const data = "2021-12-29,,,135,1, 2021-12-30,,,135,1, 2021-12-31,9999,,135,8,";
const pattern = /(?:[^,\s]*,){5}/g;

const matches = data.match(pattern);

console.dir(matches);
```